# Unable to translate "Want to improve this answer" notice

Tags: bug, moderator-tools, localization, post-notices

There's no string to translate notice (can be added by mods manually) on [answer](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/118283/176217):

> [image]

> Want to improve this answer? Add details and include citations to explain why this answer is correct. Answers without enough detail may be edited or deleted.

Similar (previous revision?) [text exists](https://ru.traducir.win/strings/13317) on traducir, but contains "post" word instead of "answer" and some other minor differences.